# Finding an equation of a line segment- analytical geometry

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The question is: Find an equation for the line containing line segment AB. I kind of understand (slope equation, altitude, and all the formulas). I'm just not sure the steps and process of answering a question like this/ when to use certain equations. - please explain clearly. The Cartesian plane with the line segment is shown below.

[image: normal_line_through_point]

Comment: Do you know the slope of $AB$?

Comment: Since you write that you "kind of understand", please share what you understand.

Comment: No I do not know the slope of AB, I believe you have to find it. I think my teacher finds the coordinates of B somehow, and then finds the slope of AB? As well, I added what I understand into the question.

Comment: @joeb  You made a formatting error (I suspect a missed dollar sign) that makes your comment unreadable.

Comment: @joeb  Now, all the comments are rendering strangely on my computer.

Comment: Very strange - went on a mobile device to delete my previous comments, and now the desktop site is rendering comments normally again. Hmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it (Of course, there are many others):

---

The function for a line is given by $y=-2x-2$. Note the general equation for a line:
$$y=mx+b \tag{1}$$
Note that the line segment $AB$ is perpendicular to that. Let's calculate the slope of $AB$ (Let's call this $m$) using the slope of the line given. Here, $m_1$ is the slope of the line you are given $y=-2x-2$. We can evidently see that $m_1=-2$. Therefore:
$$m=-\frac{1}{m_1}=\frac{1}{2}$$
We now have $m$, now substitute it into $(1)$ and evaluate $b$ using a known point you have on the line segment $AB$. In this case, you can use $A(1,0)$.

---

Here is more [intuition](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m847jg34pz) about *why* you have to find $b$. Since you already have the slope of $AB$, what you want to do is **align** the function to $AB$. Try moving the slider for $b$ on the link I've attached.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I am confused where you got m=-1/m1. Also, what equation would you use to find m? What would you find by substituting and evaluating?

Comment: Remember how to find the slope of a line perpendicular to another line? You may have seen this before:
$$m_2=-\frac{1}{m_1}$$
Or alternatively, you may have seen this too:
$$m_1\times m_2=-1$$

Comment: Would finding the slope give you the equation? and I would do m=-1/2? Solve that, and then sub into y=mx+b? I have seen, m=y2-y1/x2-x1

Comment: Well, actually in this case, since the slope of the other line (Which I called $m_1$) is $-2$, the slope of the line segment $AB$ would be $m=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Okay, so then I take 1/2 and sub that into y=mx+b? Solving for the slope of the other line and y intercept?

Comment: Yes, you take $m=\frac{1}{2}$. Now, you know that $A(1,0)$ is on the line segment $AB$. Substitute that in $y=mx+b$ and solve for $b$. Feel free to tell me what you get from solving it.

Comment: @helpneeded I edited my answer to make it clearer. Does it help?

Comment: Hi sorry, I was eating dinner lol. Ya I answered it and got b=-1/2. Would this be correct? And if so, the equation would just be y=1/2x+/1/2?

Comment: No problem! Your value for $b$ is certainly correct. Your line equation may be a typo (Just a sign mistake). It should be: $$y=\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}$$ You can see that it is correct using the link I provided with the graphs.

Comment: Oh ya I meant -! I think I do understand now, thank you for your help- much appreciated! I believe my only question is how you got AB m=1/2? Did you just do the negative reciprocal

Comment: Yes: $$m=-\frac{1}{m_1}=-\frac{1}{-2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Okay, Will do! Thanks a bunch